# Remote "in-house" bounded context integration

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my company we have two "applications" - one is essentially a big CMS for product department to manage products, promos, customers etc. The second one is more or less e-commerce solution which is a direct consumer of CMS bounded context. The thing is, we share infrastructure - mainly databases. This is the origin of `Product` in e-commerce BC - it's loaded from table maintained by CMS. In [Implementing DDD by Vernon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) author mentions several ways to integrate such remote BCs (REST/RPC/Messaging) but I haven't encountered that scenario anywhere. From performance perspective it's probably (and correct me if I'm wrong) best to use those CMS tables in e-commerce BC.

Now:

- Should I create a **Inventory context** in e-commerce that would serve as a integration bridge between CMS and e-commerce BCs?
- Should I move persistence models from CMS to some kind of shared kernel and use it on both BCs?

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Database integration is an option also, although it is not desired by DDD.

You may use rpc query from the CMS hidden behind a domain service or ProductRepository in e-commerce bounded context if you want to avoid direct database manipulation. I believe this is the minimal cost approach.

On the other hand, e-commerce bounded context may have its own database, the product data needed could be replicated by messages published by CMS bounded context. But I think it is a big overhaul on both bounded contexts.